# Excel Conditional summation of rows

Tags: excel-formula, sumifs, excel-indirect

Hi all, I have a problem with a formula with SUMIFS and INDIRECT.

I want to sum up the lines in the D column that does not have the "AL" in the B column.

The number of lines between the sum of the row where the formula is and D6 will increase and vary.

I get the error #VALUE!
The formula is:

```
=SUMIFS(D6:INDIRECT("R[-1]C";0);B6:INDIRECT("R[-1]C";0);"<>AL")
```

[examples of my excel worksheet layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBUqL.png)

The line above having the formula =SUM(D6:INDIRECT("R[-1]C",0)) works great

I think that the formula should work but it doesn't.

Anyone who can figure out what is wrong with the formula?

Thanks!

/martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the SUMIFS function, the criteria_range needs to be in a single column. In the INDIRECT function you are using an absolute start column with a relative end column which results in multiple columns. Need to use an absolute end column. For example, change...

```
=SUMIFS(D6:INDIRECT("R[-1]C";0);B6:INDIRECT("R[-1]C";0);"<>AL")
```

to...

```
=SUMIFS(D6:INDIRECT("R[-1]C";0);B6:INDIRECT("R[-1]C2";0);"<>AL")
```